# The full entropy quote

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question, entropy

What is the full text (and possibly the source) of the summary of the 3 laws of thermodynamics that goes something along the lines of "Can't break even, can't win and can't even stop playing the game"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This comes from the pioneering work of amateur physicist Michael Jackson:

> You can't win,
> You can't break even,
> And you can't get out of the game.
> People keep sayin',
> Things are gonna change.
> But they just look like<
> They're stayin' the same.

-Charlie Smalls, "[You Can't Win](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YrinCQOxB0)" as performed by Michael Jackson

Okay, okay. I think this is one of those jokes that starts between graduate students or something by the water cooler, so it doesn't have an "exact" form. [Wikiquotes gives](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Thermodynamics) the original author as [C.P. Snow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.P._Snow) in the following form:

> Zeroth: "You must play the game." 
> First: "You can't win." 
> Second: "You can't break even." 
> Third: "You can't quit the game."

But that seems somewhat dubious. No one can provide a cite of C.P. Snow actually saying or writing it anywhere; I suspect that this history is a little mythical and that the joke has no real precise statement.

Comment: I can't see how First could say "you can't win", that's really Second. At best First says "If you have what it takes, your in the game".  Second: "But you can't even break even". Third: "Unless you die".  Forget Zeroth, never liked him.